# Multiple Long-Running Background Tasks

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, background-process, background-task

I am working on an app where I would have to implemented at least two background tasks. The scenario becomes like this, I have a web service which tells me when to start the location updates for a user. So, I would need to periodically call this service to check if it's time to start, and/or stop, user's location tracking.
So there are two background tasks, fetch and location tracking. Fetch should run periodically which defies Apple's procedure that it will monitor your app's usage and decide on it's own when to update the content. This has become my first problem, is there any way that I can avoid this? The second problem comes with the multiple tasks, how can I switch between either of them?
What is the best practice here? Dos and Don'ts?

Comment: Best practice would be for your server to push a notification to the app when location monitoring should start/stop.  If the app has been terminated then this won't work, but your push can include a payload that prompts the user to launch your app. The location stuff is straight-forward background location

Comment: That is a very good way of looking at things. But wouldn't a dubious push notification disrupt a user experience?

Comment: If you specify a silent push (content-available:1) then the message is just delivered to your app without a notification *unless* your app is terminated in which case the notification is shown to the user.  The app should only be terminated if the user does so via the task switcher

Comment: Agreed but what if the app is not running? The updates are part of a very crucial feature and we would not want to miss them.

Comment: Then, to be blunt, target another platform.  On iOS the user is in control.  They can turn off location services. They can remove your app's permission to use location services and they can terminate your app (They can also turn off the phone, go out of coverage or delete the app).  This sort of update is always going to be "best effort".  That is why you can include a notification payload that is only displayed if the app isn't running that prompts the user to run the app.  Whether they do or not is out of your control

Comment: Alright, great. I would revolve around the idea. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Push notifications through Apple's push servers, or you may find a service like Parse.com easier to work with. You can use the push notification to trigger or create anything in your app delegate (where you handle receiving push notifications). As @Paulw11 's comment states, you can even attach a payload(data) to a push notification and deal with it. So the first part is fire a notification to the user's device when they should start tracking and end tracking.

Most location tracking stuff using an instance of a CLLocationManager can be done via it's delegate methods. However if you want you can use it in a subclass of an NSOperation and manage it in an NSOperationQueue, see here for a tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift

And I suggest researching the class documentation.